# Mule: Best approach to design a flow

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am looking for a correct approach to design a flow. If I want to perform database operations on 5 different tables, do I need 5 database nodes? or if I want to declare 3 flow variables, do I need 3 Variable transformers? I think this makes flow look complex unnecessarily. Can I write multiple queries in one database node? If I don't want to write a java class, What should be the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions one by one :-

1. **`If I want to perform database operations on 5 different tables, do I need 5 database nodes?`**

No .. It can be achieved by a single DB connector performing different operations.
Pls go through the documentation here :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/database-connector.
You need to define single global db connector that connects your db and that can be referred by multiple DB component in the flow performing different operations (select, insert, update etc). pls check here :-
[Write Multiple queries in database connector in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687664/write-multiple-queries-in-database-connector-in-mule)

2. **`if I want to declare 3 flow variables, do I need 3 Variable transformers?`**

Not necessary , it can be done using `<message-properties-transformer/>` where you can define multiple variables in one component at a time with **`scope="invocation"`** property. example :-

```
 <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties" scope="invocation">
     <add-message-property key="var1" value="value1"/>
     <add-message-property key="var2" value="value2"/>
 </message-properties-transformer>
```

3. **`Can I write multiple queries in one database node?`**

For insert, delete, update operations you can have multiple queries in one DB component using **bulk** option ref:- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/database-connector#bulk-updates :-

```
<db:bulk-execute config-ref="dbConfig">
    update TABLE1 set NAME='Mercury' where POSITION=0;
    update TABLE1 set NAME='Mercury' where POSITION=4
 </db:bulk-execute>
```

You can also refer here :- http://www.slideshare.net/anir37/mule-db-bulk-execute

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks Anirban. Will check it out.

Comment: But in case I want to fire queries based on some conditions in that case can we use Bulk mode option?

Comment: Yes.. I have just given an example :)