# Write Multiple queries in database connector in Mule

Tags: mule, database-connection, mule-component

I want to write select and insert queries for 3 tables for the same database using a database connector. I want to know is there a alternative or how can it be done using 1 database connector?

I ended up using 5 database connector. But I think this makes the flow look complicated. Is there any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in a wrong way :)
It can be achieved by a single DB connector performing 3 different operations.
Pls go through the documentation here :-  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/database-connector

You need to define single global db connector that connects your db :-

```
<db:generic-config name="GlobalDB_Config" url="jdbc:sqlserver://${mssql.server}:${mssql.port};databaseName=${mssql.database};user=${mssql.user};password=${mssql.password}"  driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"   doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
```

and then you can perform different operations (select, insert, update etc) in your flow using different db component referring to the same global db connector :-

```
 <db:insert config-ref="GlobalDB_Config">
    <db:parameterized-query>INSERT INTO TABLE1(POSITION, NAME) VALUES (777, #[payload])</db:parameterized-query>
 </db:insert>
```

or

```
<db:select config-ref="GlobalDB_Config">
  <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT POSITION from TABLE1 WHERE NAME = '#[message.inboundProperties['NAME']]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
```

Comment: I am creating one global connector and referring the same for multiple db connectors. But my question is there a way to use 1 db connector?  because if we see the flow then it has 4-5 db connectors for 4-5 operations.

Comment: That is not called connector .. Connector is the one you define globally with your DB connection parameters like DB url, DB user name, DB passwords etc .. The thing that you define in your flow for Db operations  is called database component

Comment: I said db connector because the toolkit says db connector when you hover the cursor on the connectors tab.

Comment: Is there a way for doing this in one db component where we write one parameterized query , can we write mutliple queries?

Comment: There is an option called `db:bulk-execute` where you can define multiple queries ... ref:- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/database-connector#bulk-updates  ... but has certain limitations like :- It only supports insert, delete, update operations and there was a bug using it with dynamic queries :- https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/33091/bulk-query-multiple-inserts-not-working.html ... not sure if it is fixed now